# Flutter socket is not connecting

Tags: sockets, flutter, websocket

I am trying to develop a flutter app which connects to the socket . The server is in Node js  Websockets to implement this functionality.
The problem I am facing is, my flutter app is not able to connect to the server and throws following error.

```
I/flutter (18793): WebSocketChannelException                            
I/flutter (18793): WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://jamunity.oneclickitmarketing.co.in:0#' was not upgraded to websocket
```

Comment: Hi, would it be possible to add a snippet of the Flutter code into the question?
It's hard for others to understand the issue without this.

Comment: Hi, i try your url with https://www.websocket.org/echo.html this but not working you have to user wss in socket implemention so ur url must be start with wss://www.websocket.org/echo.html like this :)